# select data from internal json in jsonb postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following table structure:

```
create table system_log
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    details jsonb
);
```

Data in 'details' column is json with inner json:

```
{
  "prop1": "value1",
  "prop2": "value2",
  "body": "{\"prop3\": \"value3\"}"
}
```

How to select data from inner json like 'select details.body.prop3 ...' ?

Comment: The data you should is invalid JSON. Update question with an actual valid value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver im not going to post actual data, but i corrected json in sample, it should be valid now

Comment: Sort of, but this `"{\"prop3\": \"value3\"}"` is going to present a problem: `select '{"prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "body": "{\"prop3\": \"value3\"}"}'::jsonb -> 'body' ->> 'prop3'; NULL` vs `select '{"prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", "body": {"prop3": "value3"}}'::jsonb -> 'body' ->> 'prop3'; value3`. Are you sure that is how the embedded object is specified? If so there seems be an input error where it is coming in as a string not an object.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yeah i always got NULL as result for whatever i tried. example is the same structure we have right now. so your point is internal json stored in wrong way? i was thinking about it as well..

Comment: Yes, the value for the `"body"` key is a quoted string `"{\"prop3\": \"value3\"}"`. That means it is not searchable using the methods proposed in the answers below. I presume what you really want there is the object `{"prop3": "value3"}`. You will need to delve into the process that is creating the data for the field `details` to see if that can be corrected.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it works. post your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: 1) What works? 2) If it is changing `"{\"prop3\": \"value3\"}"` --> `{"prop3": "value3"}` then the existing answers already cover that. 3) If not then you will need to show what you did.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, i changed some java side to store it as object (json) instead of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "body" stored as string instead of object json.

was:

```
{
  "prop1": "value1",
  "prop2": "value2",
  "body": "{\"prop3\": \"value3\"}"
}
```

should be

```
{
  "prop1": "value1",
  "prop2": "value2",
  "body": {"prop3": "value3"}
}
```

This is why all other suggested answers returned "NULL" as result.
Thanks for @AdrianKlaver

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
insert into system_log values (1, 
'{
"prop1":"value1",
"prop2":"value2",
"body":{"prop3":"value3"}
}');
```

You could query like this

```
select jsonb_path_query(details ,'$.body.prop3 ') 
from system_log sl;
```

Or also use a condition

```
select jsonb_path_query(details ,'$.body.prop3 ? (@ =="value3")') 
from system_log sl;
```

Working sample [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iB4amAPjyjutDVTvyR77St/1)
and the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should not store JSON documents as strings in other JSON documents. Change `"body": "{\"prop3\": \"value3\"}"` to `"body": {"prop3": "value3"}`, and you can normally access the value using `details->'body'->>'prop3'` or `details#>>'{body,prop3}'`.

However, if you absolutely have to work with the nested format, you can still get the string of the inner document, convert it to `jsonb`, and then access properties of that object:

```
(details ->> 'body')::jsonb ->> 'prop3'
```